# Error 500: Internal server error deploying Symfony 6 application on shared hosting (Apache)

Tags: php, symfony

I have successfully deployed my application to a remote host using Deployer.

I'm on shared hosting and I don't have access to the Apache configuration.

The application is deployed in a directory created for an Add-on domain, that is, it is not in the main domain. This folder is into: `home/serverid/myrootadon`

When I try to navigate to the domain in which I have installed the app: `https://example.com` I get:

> Error 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this
> is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for
> further assistance.

I don't understand what causes this error. I've tried looking in the error logs, but can't find anything.

In the root folder there is an `error_log` file only with this:

> [01-Jun-2023 15:23:46 UTC] 2023-06-01T15:23:46+00:00 [info] User
> Deprecated: The "Monolog\Logger" class is considered final. It may
> change without further notice as of its next major version. You should
> not extend it from "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger".

In the `var/log` folder, there is one file called `dev.log` with this:

> 2023-06-01T15:46:05.158715+00:00] deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated:
> The "Monolog\Logger" class is considered final. It may change without
> further notice as of its next major version. You should not extend it
> from "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger". {"exception":"[object]
> (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The "Monolog\Logger"
> class is considered final. It may change without further notice as of
> its next major version. You should not extend it from
> "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger". at
> /home/serverid/myrootadon/releases/4/vendor/symfony/error-handler/DebugClassLoader.php:338)"}
> []

I have this:

```
# Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

in two `.htaccess` files: `/home/serverid/myrootadon/.htaccess` and `/home/serverid/myrootadon/public_html/.htaccess`.

The database connection is working, if I do this from the console:

```
$ php current/bin/console  dbal:run-sql "SELECT * from post";
```

I can see the rows into the `post` table.

And the routes are defined:

```
$ php current/bin/console debug:router

 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
  _preview_error             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
  _wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
  _profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
  _profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
  _profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
  _profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
  _profiler_xdebug           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/xdebug                  
  _profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
  _profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                    
  _profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
  _profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
  _profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
  _profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
  app_post                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /post                              
  post_show                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /post/{id}                         
 -------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

If I try to navigate to: `https://example.com/post/1` I have Error 500 too, when the post with id=1 exists in the database.

All this works perfectly locally but when I deploy it to the remote server I can't get it to work nor can I find where the 500 error is. I don't see anything in the browser console either.

Comment: `info` level messages are irrelevant. If Apache is not writing a proper error message in the log files increase the log level.

Comment: It's also possible that the log you checked comes from PHP, not from Apache. In that case check the correct log files.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider in `monolog.yaml` I have: `level: debug`

Comment: This does not affect Apache logging.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I don't have access to Apache logs, because I'm working in a shared hosting.

Comment: Then contact your hoster. The web server logs are your only chance to find the problem.